# Geth will not start mining in private network!

Tags: go-ethereum, mining, private-blockchain, testnets

Will somebody please help me out? I am stuck at this since hours; did the process +3 times, each time deleting the datadir content. Geth still will not start mining!!

Specs:
*Geth 1.8.11, on macOS X*

This is what I did:

### 1. Used this genesis.json file

```
{
  "difficulty" : "0x20000",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "0x8000000",
  "alloc": {},
  "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0,
        "eip155Block": 0,
        "eip158Block": 0
    }
}
```

### 2. Ran geth with these two commands

Initialized the private chain `geth --datadir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata init /Users/shaikhaalothman/genesis/genesis.json` then started geth `geth --datadir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata`

---

```
Last login: Mon Jun 25 22:15:52 on ttys000
Shaikhas-MacBook-Pro:~ shaikhaalothman$ geth --datadir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata init /Users/shaikhaalothman/genesis/genesis.json
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth/chaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=11.447µs gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=chaindata                                       hash=0613eb…9a64e7
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth/lightchaindata cache=16 handles=16
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Writing custom genesis block 
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Persisted trie from memory database      nodes=0 size=0.00B time=4.588µs  gcnodes=0 gcsize=0.00B gctime=0s livenodes=1 livesize=0.00B
INFO [06-25|22:20:29] Successfully wrote genesis state         database=lightchaindata                                       hash=0613eb…9a64e7
Shaikhas-MacBook-Pro:~ shaikhaalothman$ geth --datadir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata 
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Maximum peer count                       ETH=25 LES=0 total=25
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.8.11-stable-dea1ce05/darwin-amd64/go1.10.3
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth/chaindata cache=768 handles=128
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Initialised chain configuration          config="{ChainID: 15 Homestead: 0 DAO: <nil> DAOSupport: false EIP150: <nil> EIP155: 0 EIP158: 0 Byzantium: <nil> Constantinople: <nil> Engine: unknown}"
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Disk storage enabled for ethash caches   dir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth/ethash count=3
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Disk storage enabled for ethash DAGs     dir=/Users/shaikhaalothman/.ethash               count=2
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Initialising Ethereum protocol           versions="[63 62]" network=1
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Loaded most recent local header          number=0 hash=0613eb…9a64e7 td=131072
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Loaded most recent local full block      number=0 hash=0613eb…9a64e7 td=131072
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Loaded most recent local fast block      number=0 hash=0613eb…9a64e7 td=131072
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Regenerated local transaction journal    transactions=0 accounts=0
INFO [06-25|22:20:39] Starting P2P networking 
INFO [06-25|22:20:41] UDP listener up                          self=enode://de764357ef765c4cb6fb7aed6e97b895d1f67837ce3764a5dcf138e7f48a5044a81d68d54c18d653a825784bb52e90220ab05f42c176d44cf44b242985bc2118@[::]:30303
INFO [06-25|22:20:41] RLPx listener up                         self=enode://de764357ef765c4cb6fb7aed6e97b895d1f67837ce3764a5dcf138e7f48a5044a81d68d54c18d653a825784bb52e90220ab05f42c176d44cf44b242985bc2118@[::]:30303
INFO [06-25|22:20:41] IPC endpoint opened                      url=/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc
INFO [06-25|22:22:27] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [06-25|22:22:27] Transaction pool price threshold updated price=18000000000
INFO [06-25|22:22:27] Starting mining operation 
INFO [06-25|22:22:27] Commit new mining work                   number=1 txs=0 uncles=0 elapsed=72.379ms
INFO [06-25|22:23:14] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
INFO [06-25|22:29:59] Updated mining threads                   threads=1
```

### 3. Launched Mist with the private network ipc file

Launched Mist with command `/applications/mist.app/contents/macos/mist --rpc /Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc`

---

```
Last login: Mon Jun 25 22:20:14 on ttys000
Shaikhas-MacBook-Pro:~ shaikhaalothman$ /applications/mist.app/contents/macos/mist --rpc /Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc
[2018-06-25T22:21:00.528] [INFO] Settings - Running in production mode: true
[2018-06-25T22:21:00.616] [INFO] EthereumNode - undefined 'light' 'light'
[2018-06-25T22:21:00.618] [INFO] EthereumNode - Defaults loaded: geth main light
[2018-06-25T22:21:00.784] [INFO] main - Starting in Mist mode
[2018-06-25T22:21:03.580] [INFO] Db - Loading db: /Users/shaikhaalothman/Library/Application Support/Mist/mist.lokidb
[2018-06-25T22:21:03.691] [INFO] Windows - Creating commonly-used windows
[2018-06-25T22:21:03.693] [INFO] Windows - Create secondary window: loading, owner: notset
[2018-06-25T22:21:07.847] [INFO] updateChecker - Check for update...
[2018-06-25T22:21:12.839] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: main, owner: notset
[2018-06-25T22:21:12.859] [INFO] Windows - Create primary window: splash, owner: notset
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.141] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Web3 not yet initialized, doing so now with HttpProvider.
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.161] [INFO] updateChecker - App is up-to-date.
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.162] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.163] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.307] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Meteor starting up...
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.308] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Meteor starting up...
[2018-06-25T22:21:19.309] [INFO] (ui: popupWindow) - Meteor starting up...
[2018-06-25T22:21:20.585] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2018-06-25T22:21:20.586] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for new client binaries config from: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ethereum/mist/master/clientBinaries.json
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.038] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - No "skippedNodeVersion.json" found.
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.040] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Initializing...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.041] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Resolving platform...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.042] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Calculating possible clients...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.044] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - 1 possible clients.
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.044] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verifying status of all 1 possible clients...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.045] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Verify Geth status ...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.891] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.892] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking for Geth sanity check ...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.892] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2018-06-25T22:21:21.895] [INFO] ClientBinaryManager - Checking sanity for Geth ...
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.210] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.213] [INFO] Sockets/node-ipc - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.214] [INFO] NodeSync - Ethereum node connected, re-start sync
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.215] [INFO] NodeSync - Starting sync loop
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.216] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.217] [INFO] Sockets/4 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.218] [INFO] main - Connected via IPC to node.
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.233] [INFO] Sockets/2 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.234] [INFO] Sockets/4 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.444] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2018-06-25T22:21:23.445] [INFO] (ui: splashscreen) - Network is privatenet
[2018-06-25T22:21:27.479] [INFO] NodeSync - Sync has been skipped
[2018-06-25T22:21:27.480] [INFO] NodeSync - Sync loop ended
[2018-06-25T22:21:27.481] [INFO] main - Loading Interface at file:///Applications/Mist.app/Contents/Resources/app.asar/interface/index.html
[2018-06-25T22:21:28.710] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:28.711] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:29.392] [INFO] (ui: mist) - Web3 already initialized, re-using provider.
[2018-06-25T22:21:29.644] [INFO] (ui: mist) - Meteor starting up...
[2018-06-25T22:21:29.658] [INFO] (ui: mist) - Initialise Mist Interface
[2018-06-25T22:21:31.209] [INFO] (ui: mist) - Network is privatenet
[2018-06-25T22:21:33.649] [INFO] (ui: mist) - did-navigate wallet https://wallet.ethereum.org/
[2018-06-25T22:21:33.706] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Disconnecting...
[2018-06-25T22:21:33.969] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:33.970] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.247] [INFO] (ui: mist) - did-navigate browser https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.249] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Disconnecting...
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.253] [INFO] Sockets/6 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.255] [INFO] Sockets/6 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.314] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.315] [INFO] Sockets/3 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.505] [INFO] Sockets/5 - Connect to {"path":"/Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc"}
[2018-06-25T22:21:34.506] [INFO] Sockets/5 - Connected!
[2018-06-25T22:21:36.584] [INFO] (ui: mist) - did-navigate-in-page wallet https://wallet.ethereum.org/
[2018-06-25T22:21:36.701] [INFO] (ui: mist) - dom-ready wallet https://wallet.ethereum.org/
[2018-06-25T22:21:40.442] [INFO] (ui: mist) - did-stop-loading wallet https://wallet.ethereum.org/
[2018-06-25T22:21:41.252] [INFO] (ui: mist) - dom-ready browser https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases
[2018-06-25T22:21:42.799] [INFO] (ui: mist) - did-stop-loading browser https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases
```

### 4. I ran geth attach

I ran `geth attach /Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc`
, then set `miner.setEtherbase("f8ddc84985c88e209a9f345bd6e87e9373cf386c")`, and started mining via `miner.start(1);`

---

```
Last login: Mon Jun 25 22:20:53 on ttys001
Shaikhas-MacBook-Pro:~ shaikhaalothman$ geth attach /Users/shaikhaalothman/chaindata/geth.ipc
Welcome to the Geth JavaScript console!

instance: Geth/v1.8.11-stable-dea1ce05/darwin-amd64/go1.10.3
 modules: admin:1.0 debug:1.0 eth:1.0 miner:1.0 net:1.0 personal:1.0 rpc:1.0 txpool:1.0 web3:1.0

> miner.setEtherbase("f8ddc84985c88e209a9f345bd6e87e9373cf386c")
true
> miner.start(1);
null
> miner.start(1);
null
> miner.start(1);
null
>
```

I am out of ideas as to what is wrong. If you have any ideas... your input will be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are attempting to create a private chain (with ID 15) but only initialize the files for it. Then you launch Mist which starts a production geth node instead of connecting to a node which runs on your private chain. Between the init and launching Mist, there could be another command to start a private mining node using your genesis block and inited files to which you can connect your Mist client.

Answer (score 1):

When I was setting up my own private ethereum network I was using the following github repository: https://github.com/vertigobr/ethereum

It helped me a lot to understand the requirements for proper setup. There's also an article explaining everything. You can find it here: https://medium.com/@andrenit/buildind-an-ethereum-playground-with-docker-part-1-introduction-80be173aaa7a

If my understanding of the topic is correct you may need to start "bootnode" before running any nodes/miners on that private network. I also had problems with miner not doing its work and the reason was that it couldn't connect to any peers. In my case the issue was with the URL to bootnode. Setting it up correctly fixed the error and made mining/deploying Smart Contracts possible.

I hope that helps! Even if the answer is not correct that article I shared is a good place to start. (I'm not the author, I'm just sharing it.)